Which experiments can offer insights about Hubbard $U$ parameter?
When considering $\mathrm{DFT}+U$ calculations, people either go with (1) first-principles approach: calculating the $U$ parameter using linear response theory, $\mathrm{DFPT}$, $\mathrm{ACBN0}$, etc., or (2) empirical approach: tuning the U parameter to reproduce experimentally known band gaps.
I am interested if there is any experimental method which can directly, or indirectly estimate the Hubbard $U$ parameter that is effective in the material. We do not then need to run calculation varying $U$ values and neither we need to calculate $U$ from expensive first-principles approaches. We can simply analyze the experimentally available data to have an estimate of the $U$ values and use that in our $\mathrm{DFT}+U$ calculation.

People who are downvoting the question, I would appreciate if you describe your reasoning to do so. Is this question trivial in someway? not following some of the Physics SE policy? needs to be improved/more precise?


When considering $\mathrm{DFT}+U$ calculations, people either go with (1) first-principles approach: calculating the $U$ parameter using linear response theory, $\mathrm{DFPT}$, $\mathrm{ACBN0}$, etc.,
or (2) empirical approach: tuning the U parameter to reproduce experimentally known band gaps.


I am interested if there is any experimental method which can directly, or indirectly estimate the Hubbard $U$ parameter that is effective in the material.

The Hubbard $U$ is a toy model parameter. You can not really measure it "directly."
There are experimental techniques like ARPES, RIXS, and x-ray absorption that can be sensitive to electron-electron interactions and thereby can be related to model parameters like $U/t$. For example, here is an ARPES paper that purports to provide values of $U/t$.

We do not then need to run calculation varying $U$ values and neither we need to calculate $U$ from expensive first-principles approaches. We can simply analyze the experimentally available data to have an estimate of the $U$ values and use that in our $\mathrm{DFT}+U$ calculation.

I don't know if it is going to be as "simple" as you think, but sure, go for it.
Remember too that DFT calculations are just self-consistent single-particle calculations regardless of how fancy you get with your potential... So it is quite difficult, if not impossible, to capture the effects of electron-electron interaction in such a theory. In other words, a self-consistent piece of garbage is still a piece of garbage.

$U$ is a model parameter. To estimate it all you can do is to predict measured properties of your physical system and then look for the $U$ value that best explains them.

This is the second approach I described in the post and I believe this is not the only one way. Another approach is to estimate it in an ab-initio way. Anyway, If I understood you correctly, you are saying that the thing I am looking for simply does not exist. Correct?
